# jQuery sortable connectWith multiple lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists with 8 list elements within each one. I would like to drag either element into either list, and get the total order of both lists together.

Currently the order is classed as two separate sortable lists:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

However I would like it to be (obviously in the order of the elements):

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

The parameter `connectWith` doesn't seem to be working at all, and I cannot drag elements into other lists.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list-1, #list-2').sortable({
        connectWith: '.group',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var orders = new Array();
            $('#console').html('<b>posts[id] = pos:</b><br>');
            $('.group li').each(function(i) {
                var order = $(this).index();               
                var id = $(this).attr('data-post-id');
                orders.push(order);
            });
            console.log(orders)
        }
    });

});
```

[I have created a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UjQVw/1/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is with the `float:left` on the `li` items .. you need to add `float:left` to the containers too (ie the `ul`) to give them some height

[Updated your jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UjQVw/2/)

fix was changing your css to

```
ul { list-style: none; float:left;  }
```

### Update

To get the order try this :

```
$('.group li').each(function(i) {           
     var id = $(this).data('post-id');
     orders.push(parseInt(id.substr(id.indexOf('-')+1)));
});
console.log(orders)
```

Note: you should use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store/retrieve data on a node not the `attr()` method

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/UjQVw/4/)

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions on getting the correct order for them all?

Comment: This fixed my problem too! Just wondering: how could I have known this (if I had not found this post on SO)?

Comment: @IvoRenkema which bit ? the CSS or the JavaScript ?