# JQuery sortable breaks when using connectWith on sortable grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have been working with JQuery sortable grids, and have run into a strange problem where the dragging/placeholders break when there are 2 or more sortable grids linked with the `connectWith` option. So far, I have tested and confirmed the same behavior in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

It appears as though dragging ignores the mouse position and the placeholder position appears somewhat randomly.

**Example:** http://wilhall.com/tests/apptest.html

The above problem is fixed when the grids are not connected using `connectWith`:

**Example:** http://wilhall.com/tests/apptest_2.html

<strike>Instinctively, I decided to throw my code into jsfiddle to post this question, but when I did so, the error was not present when viewed on jsfiddle:</strike>

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/B2ddx/1/

The following is my configuration options for the two sortable grids:

```
       $(".modules.app").sortable({
            cursor: "move",
            distance: 1,
            revert: 100,
            scroll: true,
            tolerance: "intersect",
            opacity: 0.6,
            connectWith: ".modules.bin",
            placeholder: "placeholder",
            forcePlaceholderSize: true
        }).disableSelection();

        $(".modules.bin").sortable({
            cursor: "move",
            distance: 1,
            revert: 100,
            scroll: true,
            tolerance: "intersect",
            opacity: 0.6,
            connectWith: ".modules.app",
            placeholder: "placeholder",
            forcePlaceholderSize: true
        }).disableSelection();
```

I updated my example pages to include no external CSS or JS other than jquery and jquery-ui, and now use the same jquery & ui versions as jsfiddle, to make sure everything is kosher, but still the problem persists.

I am really stumped as to what could be causing this, and will continue posting updates as I try new solutions.

**Update:**
In JSFiddle, the `connectTo` option is not working properly, and is not actually linking the lists - which is why the problem does not exist there.

Also, the problem is not present when the sortable `li` elements are not floated.

**Update:**
As suggested, I removed any percent heights of the elements containing the sortable items, which fixed the problem but created another one: without any height (the containers took on 0 height), items could not be dragged between the two sortable grids.

To fix this, I tried adding `float:left` and/or `height: 500px` to the sortable containers, but the same problem was present.

---

Here is a ***simplified*** JSFiddle exhibiting the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/y8xrZ/

If you remove the `connectWith` option from the `.sortable` calls, the problem disappears.
Note that this error effects the sortable container that is using `connectWith`. So, in the example, removing `connectWith` just from the `#app` container fixes the problem *only* for the `#app` container, but not for the `#bin` container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to your find re jQueryUI version, I was able to work this one out.

The biggest clue is of course the behaviour when a `connectWith` option is set. I hunted through the `jquery.ui.sortable.js` file, and found that the problem seemed to be caused in the `_contactContainers` method, although I could not figure out why.

Knowing that jQuery UI 1.8.24 does work, I compared the sortable file in both. While there appear to be quite a number of differences between the two files even in the `_contactContainers` method, it seems to come down to a difference in an if-else block. In this case, the older version has a condition (`else if(this.currentContainer != this.containers[innermostIndex])`) whereas the newer one does not.

At about line 734 in `jquery.ui.sortable.js` in version 1.9.2, we see an if-else block that begins like this:

```
// move the item into the container if it's not there already
if(this.containers.length === 1) {
    this.containers[innermostIndex]._trigger("over", event, this._uiHash(this));
    this.containers[innermostIndex].containerCache.over = 1;
} else {
....
```

Just change it to this:

```
// move the item into the container if it's not there already
if(this.containers.length === 1) {
    this.containers[innermostIndex]._trigger("over", event, this._uiHash(this));
    this.containers[innermostIndex].containerCache.over = 1;
} else if(this.currentContainer != this.containers[innermostIndex]) {
```

Adding that condition to the `else` did the trick for me.

Comment: Great! This worked - perhaps this would be worthy of a ticket on the bug tracker?

Comment: @WilHall Did you submit this ticket/can you post the link to the ticket in the comments? I also ran into this issue, and am interested in its resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the explicit height and width rules you are applying to your `ul` elements are what's doing it. When I disable those rules in the `.modules` class, things seem to work properly. So, remove the following lines from the `.modules` class:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

Specifying a percentage height is generally known to be problematic anyway (or at least used to be), so I'd recommend against it.

Comment: You're right - this does fix the problem, but it creates a new one: when the `ul.modules` has no height, it is impossible to drag sortable items between the two grids. I also tried replacing the percent heights with `float: left` on `.modules` so it would have an automatic height, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: All I can figure is that this is a bug with the Sortable class. I see a few tickets in the jQuery bug tracker about this kind of issue, and I see comments about how float breaks this kind of thing because the elements no longer have any height. Too weird. Here's [an example](http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-ui-sortable-connectwith.html) that is somewhat similar to yours and seems to work.

Comment: Floats on the sortable elements or the container? Because I have tried removing it on the containers, which doesn't fix it. The example you linked to doesn't float the sortable elements. If I don't float mine, the problem disappears, so it must be due to the height like you said.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UjQVw/2/) from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9704165/1128047) seems very similar to your setup, but I can't figure out what the difference is.

Comment: It appears the problem is present in JQueryUI 1.9+. I raised the version used in the fiddle you linked until the problem occurred.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in jQuery UI 1.10.2
Had the same problem and switched to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. The example code on jQuery UI says to float your items to create a grid.  The fix for me was changing the CSS to use inline-block instead, as explained at the bottom of Ticket#4551 on jQuery UI - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4551:

Change **float: left** to **display: inline-block**

for instance:

```
<style>
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

where the html is something like:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>
       <div class="grid-box">
           ...
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>
       <div class="grid-box">
           ...
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```