# Create multiple sortable grids with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I use jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2. In my applications I have more than 1 lists, that can has more than 1 row. As you can see in [official demo](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid): it works fine with one list. But I have tried it with 2 lists, it doesn't work. Item from 1st list can not be moved to 2nd. I have created [this test page](http://jsfiddle.net/fjjqM) for better explanation. Thanks.

My simple JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sort1, #sort2').sortable().disableSelection();
});
```

Also, when I add `connectWith: '.sort'` ui incorrect define placement position. If I add `float: left` to the list, I can not move from one list to another.

Comment: @freshbm, no, this questions not about grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `connectWith` in the options of the plug in. I've updated your original JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fjjqM/1/

It moves a little oddly at the moment, so you might want to take a look at the official docs on this for more information: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: Thanks, it's works. But when I move item from one list to another, placement position defines incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by 'placement position defines incorrect'?

Comment: I cannot move 11 from 2nd list after 1 in first.

Comment: That's a different problem, and isn't related to the plugin. The new problem is related to your styles - in this updated JSFiddle I've removed the floating from your list elements and it works as expected, but just looks differently: http://jsfiddle.net/fjjqM/7/

It might be that you need to look into using a placeholder - http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-placeholder

Comment: It's seems that is a common problem with jQuery UI 1.9.x, JQuery sortable breaks when using connectWith on sortable grids

Answer (score 1):

Try this post, it has the same problem like you:

[JQuery sortable breaks when using connectWith on sortable grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514359/jquery-sortable-breaks-when-using-connectwith-on-sortable-grids)

[nick_w](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14597797/1081079) suggest that you replace some code in `jquery.ui.sortable.js` at line 734

```
// move the item into the container if it's not there already
if(this.containers.length === 1) {
    this.containers[innermostIndex]._trigger("over", event, this._uiHash(this));
    this.containers[innermostIndex].containerCache.over = 1;
} else { ...
```

with

```
// move the item into the container if it's not there already
if(this.containers.length === 1) {
    this.containers[innermostIndex]._trigger("over", event, this._uiHash(this));
    this.containers[innermostIndex].containerCache.over = 1;
} else if(this.currentContainer != this.containers[innermostIndex]) { ...
```

*Edit:* I've changed your jsfiddle to work with older version of jQuery UI and it's working fine. This should solve your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/fjjqM/6/